# How do I access content of a uicollectionviewcell in a view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying add a bottom border to a textfield inside a UICollectionViewCell, I registered the cell inside a view controller where my collection view is. But to set the size of the bottom border I need to the it own size, and I don't know how to do it inside the collection view cell, so Im trying to pass It to the view controller where It Is registered, but no success yet.

***Obs: I cut out some parts of the code because is not relevant.**

**UICollectionViewCell**

```
class NameStepCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let safeAreaHolder: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let title: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
        label.text = "What is\nyour\nname?"
        return label
    }()

    let txtFieldStack: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.alignment = .center
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.spacing = 20
        return stack
    }()

    let nameField: UITextField = {
        let txtFld = UITextField()
        txtFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        txtFld.textContentType = UITextContentType.name
        txtFld.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.words
        txtFld.autocorrectionType = .no
        txtFld.textColor = UIColor.black
        return txtFld
    }()

    let lastNameField: UITextField = {
        let txtFld = UITextField()
        txtFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        txtFld.textContentType = UITextContentType.familyName
        txtFld.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.words
        txtFld.autocorrectionType = .no
        txtFld.textColor = UIColor.black
        return txtFld
    }()




    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configuringView()
        configuringTitle()
        configuringTxtField()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configuringView(){
        addSubview(safeAreaHolder)
        safeAreaHolder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaHolder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        safeAreaHolder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaHolder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    }

    func configuringTitle(){
        safeAreaHolder.addSubview(title)

        title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func configuringTxtField(){
        safeAreaHolder.addSubview(txtFieldStack)

        txtFieldStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        txtFieldStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        txtFieldStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.leadingAnchor).isActive = true


        txtFieldStack.addArrangedSubview(nameField)
        txtFieldStack.addArrangedSubview(lastNameField)


        nameField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
        lastNameField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true

    }
}
```

**UIViewController**

```
class SignupViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{


    let stepsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return collectionView
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stepsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        stepsCollectionView.delegate = self

        stepsCollectionView.register(NameStepCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "nameStepId")
        stepsCollectionView.register(GenderStepCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "genderStepId")
        stepsCollectionView.register(BirthdayStepCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "birthdayStepId")
        stepsCollectionView.register(EmailStepCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "emailStepId")
        stepsCollectionView.register(PasswordStepCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "passwordStepId")

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        configuringBottomButton()
        configuringStepCollectionView()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }


    Here is where I try to get the nameFied to add the border
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        NameStepCell().self.nameField.addBottomBorder()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.item == 1 {
            let genderCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "genderStepId", for: indexPath)
            return genderCell
        }else if indexPath.item == 2{
            let birthdayCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "birthdayStepId", for: indexPath)
            return birthdayCell
        }else if indexPath.item == 3{
            let emailCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emailStepId", for: indexPath)
            return emailCell
        }else if indexPath.item == 4{
            let passwordCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "passwordStepId", for: indexPath)
            return passwordCell
        }

        let nameCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "nameStepId", for: indexPath)
        return nameCell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: stepsCollectionView.frame.size.width, height: stepsCollectionView.frame.size.height)
    }
}
```

**Extension to textfield to add the bottom border**

```
extension UITextField {
    func addBottomBorder() {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 32, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
        border.cornerRadius = 2
        border.masksToBounds = true
        border.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 112/255, green: 112/255, blue: 112/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use addBottomBorder Extension directly where you did created your variable.  txtFld.addBottomBorder(). It should work.

Comment: Normally I do this for organizing my code, but I just tried it and nothing happened!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling **addBottomBar()** inside **viewDidLayoutSubviews**, you can try something like this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 1 {
        let genderCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "genderStepId", for: indexPath)
        return genderCell
    }else if indexPath.item == 2{
        let birthdayCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "birthdayStepId", for: indexPath)
        return birthdayCell
    }else if indexPath.item == 3{
        let emailCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emailStepId", for: indexPath)
        return emailCell
    }else if indexPath.item == 4{
        let passwordCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "passwordStepId", for: indexPath)
        return passwordCell
    }

    // Dequeue your NameStepCell from collection view
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "nameStepId", for: indexPath)
    if let nameCell = cell as? NameStepCell {
        // Add bottom border to it right here and return it
        nameCell.nameField.addBottomBorder()
        return nameCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Edit:**

Now you don't need to change anything in your **SignUpViewController**. Please replace your **NameStepCell** class with the below code.

```
class NameStepCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var safeAreaHolder: UIView!
    var title: UILabel!
    var txtFieldStack: UIStackView!
    var nameField: UITextField!
    var lastNameField: UITextField!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configuringView()
        configuringTitle()
        configuringTxtField()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

private extension NameStepCell {
    func configuringView(){
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.safeAreaHolder = view

        addSubview(safeAreaHolder)
        safeAreaHolder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaHolder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        safeAreaHolder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        safeAreaHolder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        self.safeAreaHolder.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func configuringTitle(){
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
        label.text = "What is\nyour\nname?"
        self.title = label

        safeAreaHolder.addSubview(title)
        title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.title.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func configuringTxtField(){
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.alignment = .center
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.spacing = 20
        self.txtFieldStack = stack

        safeAreaHolder.addSubview(txtFieldStack)

        txtFieldStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        txtFieldStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        txtFieldStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaHolder.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.txtFieldStack.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.nameField = getTextField(.name)
        self.lastNameField = getTextField(.familyName)

        txtFieldStack.addArrangedSubview(nameField)
        txtFieldStack.addArrangedSubview(lastNameField)

        nameField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
        lastNameField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true

        // After adding constraints, you should call 'layoutIfNeeded()' which recomputes the size and position based on the constraints you've set
        self.nameField.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.lastNameField.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.nameField.addBottomBorder()
        self.lastNameField.addBottomBorder()
    }

    func getTextField(_ textContentType: UITextContentType) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.keyboardType = .default
        textField.textContentType = textContentType
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .words
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.textColor = .black
        textField.placeholder = textContentType.rawValue // P.S. Remove placeholder if you don't need. 
        return textField
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, nothing appears! Is there a problem in the way I get the size of the text field in the extension??

Comment: Did you add constraints or set frame to size and position **nameField** in your NameStepCell?

Comment: No, i didn't! I was testing a thing here, and when I try to get the width of my textfield by using the "nameCell.nameField.frame.size.width" it returns 0. Is there a chance of this be the problem???

Comment: Yes. Instead of this **let txtFld = UITextField()**, you need to use something like this **let txtFld = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))**. Or you should use constraints to size and position your text field in your NameStepCell

Comment: I understood the wrong way what you sad above, I use constraints, my nameField is  inside of a stack view, witch is fixed on the borders.

Comment: I don't know why, but every thing that is in my NameCellView is returning 0 to its frame, I just got the frame of the view that I use to organize the safe area and also return 0. <UIView: 0x7ff064e08c70; **frame = (0 0; 0 0);** layer = <CALayer: 0x600000ec8dc0>>

Comment: Could you be able to share your project? Or could you just update the question by adding the rest of the code in **NameStepCell**?

Comment: @VinniciusPereira I've updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know whether it works.

Comment: I called **layoutIfNeeded()** after setting constraints to size and position **UITextField** before accessing it's frame. Then I changed all your computed properties in **NameStepCell** into stored properties.

Comment: Why did you used a extension to my class??

Comment: None of the methods inside **NameStepCell** is required outside of the class. I just used an extension to **NameStepCell** to avoid exposing those methods outside of the class.

Comment: Sarath, can I ask you a thing, why when I use layout if needed, it returns a problem with my constraints???But the app build normally

Comment: What kind of problem? When I tried your code in Xcode, it neither threw warning nor error. My debug area was clean. Could you please elaborate more on your problem?

Comment: Sarath, i just solved de problem, i moved the layoutIfNeeded to inside the cellForItemAt and the warnings is not there any more!!! TY